# Merge Pandas Dataframe: how to add columns and replace values

Tags: pandas, join, merge, concatenation

I have a dataframe df1 and want to merge other (many) dataframes df2 so that:

- Merge happens on the matching (multi-) indexes
- New columns are created if missing
- Values are replaced if the column already exists

[image]

What is the correct pandas operation to use and with what arguments? I looked into concat/join/merge/assign/append but did not find it yet.

Code for dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4'],
                    'B':['B1', 'B2' ,'B3', 'B4'],
                    'C':['C1' ,'C2', 'C3', 'C4']},
                  index = [1,2,3,4])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C':['NewC'], 'D':['NewD']},
                  index=[3])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df2.combine_first(df1)
```

Output:

```
    A   B     C     D
1  A1  B1    C1   NaN
2  A2  B2    C2   NaN
3  A3  B3  NewC  NewD
4  A4  B4    C4   NaN
```

Another way is to use `join` with `fillna`:

```
df1[['A','B']].join(df2).fillna(df1)
```

Output:

```
    A   B     C     D
1  A1  B1    C1   NaN
2  A2  B2    C2   NaN
3  A3  B3  NewC  NewD
4  A4  B4    C4   NaN
```

A third way,

```
df1a = df1.reindex(df1.columns.union(df2.columns), axis=1)
df1a.update(df2)
df1a
```

### Timings:

```
%%timeit pd.concat((df1,df2),sort=False).groupby(level=0).last()
```

> 4.56 ms ± 947 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
%%timeit 
df1a = df1.reindex(df1.columns.union(df2.columns), axis=1)  
df1a.update(df2)
df1a
```

> 2.93 ms ± 133 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
%timeit df1[['A','B']].join(df2).fillna(df1)
```

> 5.2 ms ± 89.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
%timeit df2.combine_first(df1)
```

> 5.37 ms ± 127 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Comment: `combine_first` is a good answer Scott, I didn't realize a traditional `pd.merge` on index wouldn't solve the problem here. Part of the reason is because I was unable to test as the OP posted an image rather than pasting the values in... Thanks for editing the post.

Comment: I just tested and `combine_first` seems to be quite slow given that I use it recursively (like `for row in df.itertuples(index=True):
    # ...request values from DB based on row and process them into newDF
    df =newDF.combine_first(df)` ) will try join. (will also post code example in the future)

Comment: Yes sorry, obviously it's my own request that take the time, not the `combine_first`...

Answer (score 3):

combine first is the correct way here, another alternative is concat and get last from group `level=0` (index):

```
pd.concat((df1,df2),sort=False).groupby(level=0).last()
```

Or with `df.assign`

```
df1.assign(**df2).fillna(df1)
```

---

```
    A   B     C     D
1  A1  B1    C1   NaN
2  A2  B2    C2   NaN
3  A3  B3  NewC  NewD
4  A4  B4    C4   NaN
```