# Merge two dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to merge two dataframes conditionally.

In `df1`, it has `duration`. In `df2`, it has `usageTime`. On `df3`, I want to set `totalTime`  as `df1`'s `duration` value if `df2` has no `usageTime` value.

Here is df1:

```py
>> df1
            duration
device
1110100         53.8
1110101         64.7
1110102         52.6
1110103         14.4
```

And df2:

```py
>> df2
           usageTime
deviceId
1110100         87.6
1110101         94.3
1110102         None
1110103         None
```

The next dataframe I want to create is:

```py
>> df3
          totalUsage
device
1110100         87.6
1110101         94.3
1110102         52.6
1110103         14.4
```

Things I tried:

1. `pandas.DataFrame.combine_first()`

   ```py
   df3 = df2.combine_first(df1.rename(columns={'duration': 'totalUsage'}))
   ```

   Returns:

   ```py
           totalUsage  usageTime
   device
   1110100       53.8       87.6
   1110101       64.7       94.3
   1110102       52.6       None
   1110103       14.3       None
   ```
2. `pandas.DataFrame.fillna()`

   ```py
   df3 = df2.fillna(df1)
   df3.columns = ['totalUsage']
   ```

   Returns:

   ```py
             totalUsage
   device
   1110100         87.6
   1110101         94.3
   1110102          NaN
   1110103          NaN
   ```

I am open to all ideas.

Comment: `df3 = df2.combine_first(df1.rename(columns={'duration': 'totalUsage'}))` ?

Comment: `df3 = df2.fillna(df1)` and 
`df3.columns = ['totalUsage']`

Comment: [Merge Pandas Dataframe: how to add columns and replace values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62355898/15497888)

Comment: @HenryEcker The result not as I want. `totalUsage` returned with [53.8, 64.7, 52.6, 14.3]

Comment: @mosc9575 Your solution not worked properly too. It returned with `totalUsage` column as [87.6, 94.3, NaN, NaN]

Comment: Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34989341) ?

Comment: Use `df2.usageTime = df2.usageTime.fillna(df1.duration)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the column names when using [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and then convert the result [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```py
df3 = df2.usageTime.fillna(df1.duration).to_frame(name='totalUsage')

#          totalUsage
# deviceId           
# 1110100        87.6
# 1110101        94.3
# 1110102        52.6
# 1110103        14.4
```

Comment: Exactly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34989341/how-to-remove-nan-value-while-combining-two-column-in-panda-data-frame

Comment: have to be very careful the deviceId list is exactly the same in all dataframes. Same order and no holes

Comment: @ShubhamPeriwal are you sure they have to be the same order? it doesn't seem like that's necessary when i just tested

Comment: @tdy Yeah, it does not required. New dataframes order is same as base dataframe.